# The type or namespace name 'JsonSchema' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net

I've just added a nuget package for JSON validation. The docs do not specify how to "import" this package to the project and when I add `using JsonSchema.Net` the compiler complains `The type or namespace name 'JsonSchema' could not be found`. What's going on here?

Here's how I added the package.

```
dotnet add package JsonSchema.Net --version 2.3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a namespace `JsonSchema.Net` of version `2.3.0` from the GitHub project [json-everything](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything) of this NuGet source code.

I think you might want to use `Json.Schema` instead of `JsonSchema.Net`.

There is a class [`JsonSchema`](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/blob/master/JsonSchema/JsonSchema.cs) that might help us do JSON validation.